# Open popup view on tab bar tab click in iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar

Hello i want to open Popup View on Tab Bar tab click , but don't want View controller as root view controller for that tab , here i have attach image please check it and any pointers to help me.

[image: pop up view open on tab bar click]

Answer (score 0):

Subclass your `tabbarController` and use that.  You can use `shouldSelect` delegate method of `TabbarController` to achieve this functionality. below is the pointer code how you can do that. code is not tested so convert it according to your needs

```
import UIKit

class TabBarController: UITabBarController, UITabBarControllerDelegate {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.delegate = self
    }

    func tabBarController(_ tabBarController: UITabBarController, shouldSelect viewController: UIViewController) -> Bool {
           let tabbarIndex = tabBarController.viewControllers!.index(of: viewController)!
                if  tabbarIndex == 5 {

                    let getCurrentView = tabBarController.selectedViewController!.view!

                    getCurrentView.addSubview(yourView)
                    getCurrentView.bringSubview(toFront: yourView)

                    return false
                } else {
                    return true
                }
        }
}
```

Comment: i.e my SecondViewController or i need to design it seperatley using UIView??

Comment: whatever you want to do ... either you can design UIView ... or Controller present over current context

Comment: yes but i dont want that view controller on background

Comment: the View controller on background should be other tab selected Viewcontroller like News, Videos not of 5th tab Viewcontroller

Comment: that controller will not appear if you return false in this delegate method... your last tap controller remains there

Comment: current context = your last selected controller

Comment: well make a UIView ... add stackview in it ... in stackView add 2 buttons ... and replace YourView in above code with that UIView which has stack ... give that UIView color or image according to your design ... thats it

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/206844/discussion-between-asmita-and-jawadali).